# Spring RequestBody - STATUS 415 - Simple code don't work

Tags: json, spring

Hi guys I have mega simple code looking like this:

JSON CLASS:

```
public class AddressJSON implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 341272642200865765L;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody AddressJSON addressJSON)
{

    logger.info("FIRSTNAME: "+addressJSON.getFirstName());

    return "TEST";
}
```

I use simple JSON request via chrome POSTMAN looking like this:

> {
>       "firstName": "test",
>       "lastName": "test" }

At the end I get 415 ... what I'm doing wrong maybe I forget about something ?

POSTMAN REQUEST:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16887656/postman.PNG

Comment: What does your Spring configuration look like?

Comment: <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

Comment: You should add that to your question for every one to see easily without having to read the comments

Comment: Have you tried adding `Content-Type: application/json` to POSTMAN?

Comment: My postman look like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16887656/postman.PNG

Comment: I have not used POSTMAN before, but I think that simply selecting JSON does not add the required header. Try going to header and adding `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: I added it an answer. If it's no too much trouble, it would be good if you accepted it so future readers can immediately see the solution without having to read the comments :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be in the way you are invoking the Controller for the POSTMAN client.
The client is missing the `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP Header